# Flutter - Stream has already been listened to using sockets

Tags: sockets, flutter, stream

I am kind of lost, I got the data of my Esp8266 using `Streambuilder()` function, the problem is, everytime I change screen and pop back to the screen, I get the error : **Stream has already been listened to**

I've read that I should use a `Streamcontroller` in broadcast. But I can't figure out how to suscribe, or to listen to the changes of my socket.

Now the result is I don't have anything written in my `Text` Widget.

Here is my code (simplified version with only one page)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:async';

void main() async{
  Socket sock = await Socket.connect('192.168.1.24', 80);
runApp(MyApp(sock));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  Socket socket;

  MyApp(Socket s){
    this.socket = s;
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(

        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page',
        channel : socket,
      ),

    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final Socket channel;
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title, this.channel}) : super(key: key);



  final String title;



  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();

  StreamController streamController = new StreamController.broadcast();   
//I have my controller here, but I need it to listen to my widget.channel




  void _togglePower(){
    widget.channel.write("Apero\n");

  }
  /*
  @override
  void dispose(){
    widget.channel.close(); //Faire un flush avant de close.
    super.dispose();
  }*/

  @override
  void dispose(){
    streamController.close();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {


    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(

        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(

        child: Column(

          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text("Testou",
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.amber,
                fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                fontSize: 20
              )
            ),
        color: Colors.black,
              onPressed: _togglePower,
            ),


            Form(
              child: TextFormField(
                controller: _controller,
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Send a message'),
              ),
            ),
            StreamBuilder(
              stream: streamController.stream,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 24.0),
                  child: Text(snapshot.hasData
                      ? '${String.fromCharCodes(snapshot.data)}'
                      : 'loading'),
                );
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),

    );
  }

}
```

Or maybe is there a way to make it simplier, using widget.channel.listen ?

Thanks for any help !
Have a good evening :)

Answer (score 0):

This error show when you call listen() on a single-subscription stream multiple times.
I find the following lines in the source code.

- Listening twice on a single-subscription stream is not allowed
- even after the first subscription has been canceled

So you need to change your socket to a BroadcastSteam, save an instance here and do not call asBroadcastStream() multi times.

static bcSteam = socket.asBroadcastStream();

```
bcSteam.listen((event) {
  final data = json.decode(utf8.decode(event));
  handleSocketData(data);
});
```